# Stringification of a macro value

Tags: c, string, concatenation, c-preprocessor

I faced a problem - I need to use a macro value both as string and as integer.

```
 #define RECORDS_PER_PAGE 10

 /*... */

 #define REQUEST_RECORDS \
      "SELECT Fields FROM Table WHERE Conditions" \
      " OFFSET %d * " #RECORDS_PER_PAGE \
      " LIMIT " #RECORDS_PER_PAGE ";"

 char result_buffer[RECORDS_PER_PAGE][MAX_RECORD_LEN];

 /* ...and some more uses of RECORDS_PER_PAGE, elsewhere... */
```

This fails with a message about "stray #", and even if it worked, I guess I'd get the macro names stringified, not the values. Of course I can feed the values to the final method ( `"LIMIT %d ", page*RECORDS_PER_PAGE` ) but it's neither pretty nor efficient.
It's times like this when I wish the preprocessor didn't treat strings in a special way and would process their content just like normal code. 
For now, I cludged it with `#define RECORDS_PER_PAGE_TXT "10"` but understandably, I'm not happy about it.

How to get it right?

Comment: Preprocessed correctly for me on gcc.

Comment: Example on Linux kernel: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/stringify.h?v=4.7

Comment: I would reconsider the `"%d"` in there in favor of a query variable just on general principles. `"%d"` is unlikely to be vulnerable to injection attacks, but it seems like a bad habit to get into.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The `xstr` macro defined below will stringify after doing macro-expansion.

```
#define xstr(a) str(a)
#define str(a) #a

#define RECORDS_PER_PAGE 10

#define REQUEST_RECORDS \
    "SELECT Fields FROM Table WHERE Conditions" \
    " OFFSET %d * " xstr(RECORDS_PER_PAGE) \
    " LIMIT " xstr(RECORDS_PER_PAGE) ";"
```

Comment: is this a recent requirement ? I don't recall such tricks were required last time I used stringification ...

Comment: For further reference, additional description of the mechanics (and nuance) of stringification (GNU CPP) available at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html .

Comment: Updated GCC doc link: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html#Stringizing

Comment: This doc quote explained it to me: "`There is no way to combine an argument with surrounding text and stringize it all together. Instead, you can write a series of adjacent string constants and stringized arguments.`"

Comment: @VictorSergienko: This is nothing new and nothing harmful - string literal concatenation, `char* abc = "A" "B" "C";` is in all respects equivalent to `char* abc = "ABC";` The trick here is how to get the stringized equivalent, `"B"` instead of `'B'` or `B`.

Comment: #define PE(BZL,YY) printf("ERROR - " #BZL ": result: 0x%08x!", YY); Doing:int variable1=1; PE(Test1,variable1); --> Results printing: ERROR - Test1: result: 0x1!

Comment: Be careful copy/pasting the macros in this answer into your code.  `str` in particular is a very commonly used name and can result in a lot of confusing compile errors.

Answer (score 7):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define RECORDS_PER_PAGE 10

#define TEXTIFY(A) #A

#define _REQUEST_RECORDS(OFFSET, LIMIT)                 \
        "SELECT Fields FROM Table WHERE Conditions"     \
        " OFFSET %d * " TEXTIFY(OFFSET)                 \
        " LIMIT " TEXTIFY(LIMIT) ";"

#define REQUEST_RECORDS _REQUEST_RECORDS(RECORDS_PER_PAGE, RECORDS_PER_PAGE)

int main() {
        printf("%s\n", REQUEST_RECORDS);
        return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
SELECT Fields FROM Table WHERE Conditions OFFSET %d * 10 LIMIT 10;
```

Note the indirection to _REQUEST_RECORDS to evaluate the arguments before stringifying them.

Answer (score 3):

Try double escaping your quotes

```
#define RECORDS_PER_PAGE 10
#define MAX_RECORD_LEN 10

 /*... */
#define DOUBLEESCAPE(a) #a
#define ESCAPEQUOTE(a) DOUBLEESCAPE(a)
#define REQUEST_RECORDS \
      "SELECT Fields FROM Table WHERE Conditions" \
      " OFFSET %d * " ESCAPEQUOTE(RECORDS_PER_PAGE)       \
      " LIMIT " ESCAPEQUOTE(RECORDS_PER_PAGE) ";"

 char result_buffer[RECORDS_PER_PAGE][MAX_RECORD_LEN];

int main(){
  char * a = REQUEST_RECORDS;
}
```

compiles for me. The token `RECORDS_PER_PAGE` will be expanded by the `ESCAPEQUOTE` macro call, which is then sent into `DOUBLEESCAPE` to be quoted.

Comment: But it doesn't substitute the right values because the contents of # are not evaluated first.

Comment: @Mike Forgot the double escape