# Return quoted string in C macro

Tags: c, string, macros, quotes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stringification of a macro value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653214/stringification-of-a-macro-value)

I want to write a C macro that takes a "sequence of characters" (for example, `#define macro(sequence)`) and return the quoted string `"sequence"`, so the macro should create `"\"sequence\""`. I know I can do `#sequence` but this just returns `"sequence"` which is not what I'm looking for... I must say that `"sequence"` is another macro, so I can't write it as it is in this macro since it gets "non literally" replaced. Any ideas?

Comment: If you have `#define sequence abc`, do you expect `macro(sequence)` to give you `"\"sequence\""` or `"\"abc\""`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `#sequence` but add the quotes before and after:

```
#define macro(sequence) "\"" #sequence "\""
```

The string literals will be concatenated giving you the result you want.

For example:

```
#define hello abc
printf("%s\n", macro(hello));
```

Will print `"hello"` (including the quotes).

Comment: I can't get it to work... I wrote this macro: #define disableMacro(M) _Pragma("push_macro(\"" #M "\")")

Comment: @user732274: I don't know how `_Pragma` works, but this approach works fine with `printf`: http://ideone.com/BdW4Gi

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define QUOTE(seq) "\""#seq"\""

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", QUOTE(sequence));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need one macro to expand the argument and another to add the quotes. Call the latter macro twice to add quotes around the quotes. Escaping is handled automatically in such a case.

```
#define stringify_literal( x ) # x
#define stringify_expanded( x ) stringify_literal( x )
#define stringify_with_quotes( x ) stringify_expanded( stringify_expanded( x ) )
```

Comment: this is the second day in a row i've answered this but it's easier than finding a duplicate…

Comment: Is there anything I can do in just a single line?

Comment: This will expand the macro passed as an argument, which isn't what OP wants according to his comment above.