# C Macros - avoiding macro expansion

Tags: c, linux, macros

I have the following macros

```
#define REG_PWR_CTRL 0x2D  
#define REG_FIFO_CTL 0x38

#define VERBOSE(...) \
    if(verbose) \
            printf(__VA_ARGS__);

#define READ_REGISTER(i2c_dev_file, REGISTER, variable) \
{ \
    variable = i2c_smbus_read_byte_data(i2c_dev_file, REGISTER); \
}

#define WRITE_REGISTER_VERBOSE(i2c_dev_file, REGISTER, value) \
{ \
    short int var = 0; \
    i2c_smbus_write_byte_data(i2c_dev_file, REGISTER, value); \
    usleep(100); \
    READ_REGISTER(i2c_dev_file, REGISTER, var); \
    VERBOSE(#REGISTER "    :0x%02X\n", var); \
}
```

I would like the `REGISTER` field to not be expanded in the following line
`VERBOSE(#REGISTER "    :0x%02X\n", var); \`

For example, When I write
`WRITE_REGISTER_VERBOSE(i2c_dev_fd, REG_PWR_CTRL, 0x1A);`
  `WRITE_REGISTER_VERBOSE(i2c_dev_fd, REG_FIFO_CTL, 0xC6);`
I get the output
`0x2D    :0x1A`
`0x38    :0xC6`
I would like to obtain
`REG_PWR_CTRL    :0x1A`
`REG_FIFO_CTL    :0xC6`

I came across a lot of posts that spoke about adding an extra level of indirection.
I tried the answer described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2653351/1761555 ..although I believe that that answer is for a different problem altogether..

What I did was

```
#define STRINGIFY(label) (#label)

#define WRITE_REGISTER_VERBOSE(i2c_dev_file, REGISTER, value) \
{ \
    short int var = 0; \
    i2c_smbus_write_byte_data(i2c_dev_file, REGISTER, value); \
    usleep(100); \
    READ_REGISTER(i2c_dev_file, REGISTER, var); \
    VERBOSE("%s    :0x%02X\n", STRINGIFY(REGISTER), var); \
}
```

But this still gives me the same output as before

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at [C `#define` macro for debug printing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644868/c-define-macro-for-debug-printing/) for a discussion of why the `if (verbose)` test is not good as written and what to do about it. You'll be OK if the only context in which you use `VERBOSE` is the macro WRITE_REGISTER_VERBOSE; if it gets used elsewhere, you'd need to be careful as it could cause the program to be reinterpreted (though it would most likely just generate syntax errors, but it might not be obvious why!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make `REG_PWR_CTRL` and `REG_FIFO_CTL` a value of some enum, like

```
  enum registers_en {
     REG__NONE,
     REG_PWR_CTRL = 0x2d,
     REG_FIFO_CTL = 0x38,
  };
```

Then `REG_PWR_CTRL`  becomes a real identifier of some enum value, and is not macro-expanded in something else (because an `enum` definition is not a macro definition, and is not handled by the [`cpp` preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)).

So define such an enum, and preprocess your source code (e.g. with `gcc -C -E yoursource.c > yoursource.i`)  then look (e.g. with `less yoursource.i`) inside the preprocessed file. All occurrences of `REG_PWR_CTRL` will still be there.

Be aware the the preprocessor is conceptually the first phase of a compiler: even in compilers like current [GCC 4.8](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/) where the preprocessor is *not* an external program but implemented thru a [libcpp](https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/tree/master/libcpp) internal library, the compiler works by first preprocessing the source code and obtaining a stream of [lexemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis), and then occurrences of `REG_PWR_CTRL` stay as lexemes (not as literal constants `0x2d` as when you `#define REG_PWR_CTRL 0x2d` ...).

You need to read more about the preprocessor [cpp](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/), and take the habit to look into the preprocessed form.

Another advantage of `enum`-s is that if you compile with debugging info (e.g. `gcc -g`) the debugging info hence the debugger `gdb` knows about `enum`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite understand how this would help me do the reverse-mapping..so in this case, I will still be able to obtain the value of `0x2D` from `REG_PWR_CTRL` but I don't follow how this will help me print '`REG_PWR_CTRL`'..
Also, I haven't mentioned it, but I have a lot of registers defined..not just one.

Comment: As I edited, just try using an `enum` like I suggest and look inside the preprocessed form.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works like a charm! I'm just waiting to see if this is possible to implement using `#define` before I accept yours

Comment: Is it possible to implement this functionality using *functions* rather than *macros*? If so, could you provide a template?

Answer (score 4):

I modified your code for simplicity:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define REG_PWR_CTRL       (0x2D) 
#define GET_VAR_NAME(var)  (#var)
#define VERBOSE(...)       (printf(__VA_ARGS__))
#define ANOTHER_LAYER(arg) (                                                      \
                               VERBOSE("%s = %#X; %s = %#X\n",                    \
                                       GET_VAR_NAME(REG_PWR_CTRL), REG_PWR_CTRL,  \
                                       GET_VAR_NAME(arg), arg)                    \
                           )                                                      \

int main(void)
{
    int num = 5;

    VERBOSE("%s = %#X\n", GET_VAR_NAME(REG_PWR_CTRL), REG_PWR_CTRL);
    ANOTHER_LAYER(num);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
REG_PWR_CTRL = 0X2D
REG_PWR_CTRL = 0X2D; num = 0X5
```

Comment: This is so weird..your code works as a standalone..but when I do the same in my program, it doesn't work..The only (stupid) reasons that I can think of :  
This is happening because  
1) The macros are defined in different header files  
2) My makefile is compiling small pieces before assembling them together
3) Other header file inclusions is causing this

Other than that, I see no difference between your code and mine..
Editing my original question to show my implementation of your approach

Comment: @user1761555: you need an intermediate macro like `GET_VAR_NAME`, which your question don't have.

Comment: I have now edited my post to show the use of the intermediate macro..As I had posted originally, I did try the solution in the link I referenced..it was unsuccessful though

Comment: @user1761555 It doesn't matter where your macros are `#define`d, as long as they're `#define`d before they're used.  If the macros weren't `#define`d before use, you'd get an error.

Comment: Well, then for *some* reason, it just doesn't work. I tried looking at the preprocessed output, and the macros have already been substituted with their values. Thus, the input to my `STRINGIFY()` macro is already the hex values

Comment: @user1761555 I expanded my answer to include nesting a macro.  I'm not getting the problem you're getting...

Answer (score 1):

Use macros for simple things.

This is because:

- You have more readable code
- Easier to debug as the debugger has symbols you help you
- They are very difficult to debug.

So just use functions for complex stuff. Use macros for simple stuff

Comment: More a comment (or an opinion) than an answer! You don't provide any solution to the original issue!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - I think it is silly to use long macros in the first place and hence my answer to adopt a different approach

Comment: On the fence about whether it's a comment or not but +1 because macro complexity should be very limited.