# Arduino: How to print out value of defined constants?

Tags: c, arduino, constants, arduino-ide

I'm writing code in the Arduino (1.6.5) environment.  In my code, I want to be able to define a string value, then use it and also Serial.println() it to the serial console.

For example:

```
#define THEVAL 12345      // Define the value
...
v = v + THEVAL;     // Use the value in code.
...
Serial.println("The value is: #THEVAL");      // Show the value to user (for debugging)
```

However, the compiler doesn't replace constants inside quoted strings.  I also tried [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) (C++ stringification) which indicates that you place the constant *outside* the quoted string

```
#define THEVAL 12345
...
Serial.println("This is the value: " #THEVAL);
```

but that yields a "Stray # character" error in the compiler.

I'd appreciate any insight!  Thanks!

EDIT: ODD BEHAVIOR

On testing I discovered the following:
(Note: the IP address uses commas to separate the octets because each octet is passed as a separate parameter to the EthernetServer.begin in a byte array (byte ip[] = { a, b, c, d })

```
#define IP_ADDRESS 192,168,1,1
#define IP_ADDRESS_STRING(a,b,c,d) xstr(a)"."xstr(b)"."xstr(c)"."xstr(d)
#define xstr(a) str(a)
#define str(a) #a
```

If I do the following, I get the error "IP_ADDRESS_STRING requires 4 arguments, but only one given"

```
debug("IP Address is: " IP_ADDRESS_STRING(IP_ADDRESS));
```

but if I do the following, I get the error "macro 'str' passed 4 arguments, but just takes 1"

```
debug("IP ADDRESS: " xstr(IP_ADDRESS));
```

But if I do this, it works:

```
String ipAddressString(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    return String(a) + "." + String(b) + "." + String(c) + "." + String(d);
}

debug("IP Address is: " + ipAddressString(IP_ADDRESS));
```

I'm confused - why does one macro consider IP_ADDRESS to be a single argument, and the other macro sees it as 4 arguments, while the function works correctly: it sees 4 arguments?

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653214/stringification-of-a-macro-value but it doesn't work if the constant has commas.  For example: #define THEVAL 1,2,3

Comment: [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) might help.

Comment: Hi Eugene, that was the same link I already posted in my original comment...

Answer (score 2):

```
#define XSTR(s) STR(s)
#define STR(s) #s
....
#define THEVAL 12345
....
Serial.println("The value of " STR(THEVAL) " is " XSTR(THEVAL));
```

This would output:

```
The value of THEVAL is 12345
```

Comment: But if THEVAL is set to 123,456 this fails.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> #define XSTR(s) STR(s)
> #define STR(s) #s
> ....
> #define THEVAL 12345
> ....
> Serial.println("The value of " STR(THEVAL) " is " XSTR(THEVAL));
> ```
>
> But if THEVAL is set to 123,456 this fails.

With a slight modification it also works:

```
#define STR(...) #__VA_ARGS__
```

Answer (score 0):

suggest

```
Serial.print("This is the value: ");
Serial.println( THEVAL );
```

or

```
int x = THEVAL;
Serial.print("This is the value: ");
Serial.println( x );
```

Comment: What if THEVAL includes commas?  for example: #define THEVAL 123,456

Comment: then write the value to a char buffer[100], using something like sprintf(), then write the buffer using something like Serial.println( buffer);

Answer (score 0):

> I'm confused - why does one macro consider IP_ADDRESS to be a single
>   argument, and the other macro sees it as 4 arguments, while the
>   function works correctly: it sees 4 arguments?

In the invocation `IP_ADDRESS_STRING(IP_ADDRESS)`, there is obviously only the one argument `IP_ADDRESS`, and this is true irrespective of how `IP_ADDRESS` is defined, because *argument substitution takes place* **only after** *the arguments for the invocation of a function-like macro have been identified* (ISO/IEC 9899:201x).

In the invocation `xstr(IP_ADDRESS)` with the definition `#define xstr(a) str(a)`, according to the above the parameter `a` is then replaced by the one argument `IP_ADDRESS` *after* that macro has *been expanded* (*macro replaced*), yielding `str(192,168,1,1)`, so `str` is passed 4 arguments.

In contrast to the first case, in a function call `ipAddressString(IP_ADDRESS)` the substitution of `IP_ADDRESS` takes place not after, but **before** the arguments for the function call are identified.

You can use the macro by the same two-stage technique that's utilized with `xstr()`/`str()`:

```
#define IP_ADDRESS 192,168,1,1
#define XIP_ADDRESS_STRING(abcd) IP_ADDRESS_STRING(abcd)
#define IP_ADDRESS_STRING(a,b,c,d) xstr(a)"."xstr(b)"."xstr(c)"."xstr(d)
#define xstr(a) str(a)
#define str(a) #a
debug("IP Address is: " XIP_ADDRESS_STRING(IP_ADDRESS));
```