# Is it possible to put compiler -D define string value in variable?

Tags: c, parameters

I have following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


#ifdef COMP_DEF
static const char * x = COMP_DEF;
#else
static const char * x = "NULL";
#endif

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    printf("%s\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

What I want is to compile this program with two ways. First with compiler parameter:

`-DCOMP_DEF=FOO_BAR`

and second way without this. I expect, my program would print FOO_BAR and NULL.
But when I try to compile I get following errors:

> :0:10: error: 'FOO_BAR' undeclared here
>
> (not in a function) main.c:5:25: note: in expansion of macro
> 'COMP_DEF'  static const char * x = COMP_DEF;

Is it possible to print/store in variable compiler passed macrodefine value?

Comment: What is `FOO_BAR`? `-DCOMP_DEF=FOO_BAR` translates to `static const char * x = FOO_BAR;` which then needs a definition for `FOO_BAR`. If it's supposed to be a string, then you need to write, `-DCOMP_DEF=\"FOO_BAR\"` to make sure it goes to the pre-processor as a string, not a pre-processor variable name that has to be resolved. So then you get `static const char * x = "FOO_BAR";`.

Comment: Or look up some stringification topic like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653214/stringification-of-a-macro-value.

Comment: `-DCOMP_DEF=\"FOO_BAR\"` works for me, but I prefer using -`DCOMP_DEF=FOO_BAR` and `#` in program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try this common trick usually called *stringification*:

```
#define STR_IMPL(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR_IMPL(x)

#ifdef COMP_DEF
static const char * x = STR(COMP_DEF);
#else
static const char * x = "NULL";
#endif
```

`#` followed by argument name in macro expands to string literal containing passed argument. If you do just

```
#define STR(x) #x
```

this would make `STR(COMP_DEF)` expand to `"COMP_DEF"`. To avoid this you need another level of macro expansion.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I was trying using `#` but I didn't try to expand it twice, directly.