# Use Project properties/ Macros in c++ code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, macros

I am trying to use the OutDir Macro from the Project properties within my c++ file to build a path.

But I can't find a way to assign the OutDir content to a variable in my code.

I tried this:

```
#define OUTPUT_DIR $OutDir
```

I can't seem to use this correctly.

Comment: The project settings variables are not visible to the C++ compiler... You might try, however, to set the definition in the project settings (such that the definition is passed to the compiler via option `/D`). Don't know by heart, though, where *exactly* this is to be found in the project settings, have a look a the "preprocessor options". You'd have to set something like `OUTPUT_DIR="$OutDir"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify pre-processor definitions in the "Project Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definitions" list as:

`OUTPUT_DIR=$(OutDir)`

and then you can use that macro in your source code. You may need to textify it first. i.e.

`#define TEXTIFY(x) #x`

then use it as

`TEXTIFY(OUTPUT_DIR)`

see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653214/stringification-of-a-macro-value). Although looking at this [answer](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/147883/in-assert-like-macros-the-preprocessor-stringify-o.html), it is possible that VC++ 2017 has some issues with this.

I believe you can also add the quotes into the options itself which might be a way round it.

`OUTPUT_DIR="$(OutDir)"`

Comment: I defined OUTPUT_DIR with the double quotes method and it works.
I am on VS2015.
Thanks!