# Newbie here. C function problem during execution

Tags: c

Edit: Since I understand that I need to provide more info to make it clear for you guys, I added the main function and the getchoice and also two images of the program running. My problem is that after entering the endword, I want to see the menu first and then make a choice, whereas it prompts me to give an input without showing the menu.

This function is part of a bigger program, but this is where a problem occurs.
It reads words inputed, places them into an array, until the keyword ****END is entered. However, when this keyword is entered, it doesn't go immediatelly in the specified if clause (you will see that in the code). I'm a newbie and it could be something really obvious, but any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <string.h>

#define M 50
#define N 15

void getText(char a[M][N])
{
    int i, j;
    char temp[N];
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
            if (i == 49 && j == 14) {
                printf("Maximum length of text reached.\n");
            }

            scanf("%s\n", temp);

            if (strcmp(temp, "****END") == 0) {
                printf("You entered the endkey.\n");
                return;
            }

            strcpy(a[i], temp);
        }
    }
}

int main(){

int input;

while(1){
    input = getChoice();

    if(input == 1){
        getText(text);
    }

    else if(input == 2){
        getDictionary();
    }

    else if(input == 3){
        correctText();
    }

    else if(input == 4){
        saveText();
    }

    else if(input == 5){
        getStats();
    }

    else if(input == 6){
        break;
    }

}


return 0;
}

int getChoice(){
    int temp;
printf("Choose function:\n1: Enter text\n2: Enter dictionary\n3:     Correct  text\n4: Save text\n5: Get text statistics\n6: Exit program\n");
scanf("%d", &temp);
return temp;
}
```

[Entered the endword and now it waits for input instead of showing the menu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxRb9.png)

[I inputed 2 for the second program function, then it showed the menu and proceeded to function 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7vxd.png)

Comment: What is the connection between `i` and `M` and `50`? And between `j` and `N` and `15`?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. M is defined as 50 and N is 15.

Comment: *`for(i=0;i<50;i++) { for(j=0;j<15;j++) {`* – If you want to do it that way you have to read `char` by `char`.

Comment: .. then please don't hard-code those numbers (or the `49` and `14`) and accept Swordfish's roll-back to what was posted.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. If possible, could someone explain why is the program waiting for input before showing the menu, as shown in the images? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because for every line `M` you are calling `scanf()` `N` times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the unnecessary double-nested loop, this line

```
scanf("%s\n", temp);
```

should be

```
scanf("%s", temp);
```

Usually, you should not try to match trailing whitespace with `scanf`, and the format specifier `%s` automatically filters out leading whitespace (but note that `%c` does not).

There are other faults and the code presented was originally incomplete, but notably the input length for `%s` must be restricted to prevent buffer overflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stddef.h>  // size_t
#include <ctype.h>   // isspace()
#include <stdio.h>   // scanf(), puts()
#include <string.h>  // strcmp()

// see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653214/stringification-of-a-macro-value
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define STRING(x) STRINGIFY(x)

#define LINES 50
#define COLS 15

char const *end = "****END";

// throw away everything until a newline is found
void clear(FILE *stream)
{
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getc(stream)) != EOF && ch != '\n');
}

size_t getText(char dst[LINES][COLS + 1])
{
    size_t i = 0;
    for (; i < LINES; i++) {
        char temp[COLS + 1] = { 0 };
        scanf("%" STRING(COLS) "s", temp);  // "%15s" at runtime.

        int ch;
        // if the next character is not whitespace ...
        if ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && !isspace(ch)) {
            puts("Warning: Input too long, was truncated!");
            clear(stdin);
        }

        if (strcmp(temp, end) == 0) {
            puts("You entered the endkey.");
            return i;
        }

        strcpy(dst[i], temp);
    }
    return i;
}

int main(void)
{
    // COLS + 1 ... we need space for the terminating newline character.
    char foo[LINES][COLS + 1];
    size_t n = getText(foo);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        puts(foo[i]);
}
```

The `%s` conversion specifier should never be used without specifying a width to limit the characters that get stored:

```
char foo[10];
scanf("%9s");
```