# How can I use variable width specifiers defined by a macro in sscanf()

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

I am trying to specify the width of variables in a sscanf() call based on a #define that calculates its values based on another #define.

It works when the TEST define is just a single number, but when it becomes a calculation, the code fails. Have TEST call another function that contains the calculation does not work either.

The code I am working with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define A       3
#define TEST    FUN()
#define FUN()   (A + 2)
#define STR(X)  _STR(X)
#define _STR(x) #x

int main()
{
    char input[] = "Test123";
    char output[10];

    sscanf(input, "%" STR(TEST) "s\n", output);

    printf("%s\n", output);

    return 0;
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The preprocessor doesn't to any arithmetic, it's basically a plain search and replace.

Comment: I think that `input` and `output` are swapped in the code. Destination string, in scanf, is the first parameter.

Comment: 1) Does it file in compilation phase or at runtime? 2) What output do you get?

Comment: You might consider _variable_ as something you pass in, either via command line parameter or as a variable argument to a function.  But macros are pre-processed, and not variable during runtime.

Comment: Everything is known at compile time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just build the `scanf` format string during execution. For example:

```
const int width_modifier = FUN();
char fmt[100] = {0};
snprintf(fmt, sizeof(fmt), "%%%ds\n", width_modifier);
sscanf(input, fmt, output);
```

> What am I missing here?

Preprocessor does text replacement, it doesn't calculate things. So `"%" STR(TEST) "s\n"` expands to a string containing `"%" "3 + 2" "s\n"`, which after concatenation is `"%3 + 2s"`, which is an invalid `scanf` format string.

Alternatively you can use other program to prepare the source file for compilation. A popular use is a preprocessor that preprocesses the file before compilation and that is able to calculate arithmetic. A popular choice is [m4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_(computer_language)):

```
m4_define(`A', 3)
m4_define(`FUN', `eval(A + 2)')

#include <stdio.h>
#define STR(X)  #X
int main() {
    printf("%s", STR(FUN()));
}
```

preprocessed with `m4` and compiled would output `5`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot realize an arithmetic operation as happened in your question. So, it is evaluated as `(3 + 2)` in string form while compiling.

My two cents reminiscent of [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2653351/4990642),

```
#define STRING_LENGTH 20
#define STR(x) _STR(x)
#define _STR(x) #x

{
  ...    
  fscanf(input, "%" STR(STRING_LENGTH) "s", output);
  ...
}
```

Two macros are required because if you tried to use something like `_STR` directly you would just get the string `"STRING_LENGTH"` instead of its value.

For more [click here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/cpp/Stringification.html) and [an example](https://web.archive.org/web/20191114060542/https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/languages/C-C-plus-plus/preprocessor/macros/stringify).

Comment: Thank you. Are there any good alternatives for what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


#define MAX_LENGTH 5


int main()
{
    // specify format 

    char formatStr[20] = {0};
    snprintf(formatStr, 20-1, "%s%d%s", "%", MAX_LENGTH-1, "s%u");
    printf("%s\n", formatStr);
    
    // example to use that format 

    char *input = "programming 123";
    
    char dataStr[MAX_LENGTH] = {0};
    int  dataVal;
    sscanf(input, formatStr, dataStr, &dataVal);
    printf("%s-%d\n", dataStr, dataVal);
    
    return 0;
}

output:

%4s%u
prog-21942
```