# Initialize char array with a Pascal string

Tags: c, ansi-c

An array of character shall hold a Pascal string. This array is part of a struct and shall be initialized with an expression at compile time. This is possible in that way:

```
struct V {
    char version[2];
    char pstringa[20];
    char pstringb[30];
};
struct V variable = {
    { 1, 0 },
    { 3, 'A', 'B', 'C'  },
    { "\3""XYZ" }
};
```

Now the strings in the initialization list are generated and the length can vary. Therefore it is desired to have a preprocessor macro that creates the initializer.

There is a possibility with MSVC to use `{ 3, "ABC" }` as initializer of the member `pstringa`. This could be used in a macro:

```
#define PASCAL_STRGING(s) sizeof(s)-1,s

struct V variable = {
    { 1, 0 },
    { 3, 'A', 'B', 'C'  },
    PASCAL_STRGING("XYZ")
};
```

This is unfortunately not compliant with the C89 standard. Is there a way to create the form `"\3""XYZ"` from the macro parameter "XYZ"? The number behind the backslash shall be the number of characters in the string.

I know that it would be possible to create a struct with the length byte of the Pascal string and the remaining characters. But this shall be avoided because the structs are defined in external header files.

*Edit*

Some annotations initially missing in the question:

- The [compiler](https://www.hpinfotech.ro/) is for an embedded device (AVR-ATmega).
- The structure shall be filled at compile time, because the structure is stored in flash memory.

Comment: C89 is pretty much outdated, isn't it?

Comment: I didn't test it, but maybe something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653214/stringification-of-a-macro-value

Comment: I don't think (not either with newer standards) that you could achieve that with string literals – possibly, though, with individual characters, i.e. `PASCAL_STRING(X, Y, Z)`. For longer strings I doubt, though, that you really might want to do so...

Comment: Is filling at runtime an option?

Comment: @harper, Need a C89 solution?  How about some newer version of C?

Comment: Would type punning through a union be acceptable? (Technically implementation defined behavior, but matching a `{char len; char string[19];}` and `char pstring[20];` is probably safe)

Comment: @Hasturkun Although unlikely, there may be padding between `len` and `string`.  A `static_assert()` could test.

Comment: @Aconcagua your right, but I can't change it.

Answer (score 2):

Hacky approach: overwrite:

```
#define PASCAL_STRING(f, s)     f = " " s, f[0] = sizeof(s)-1

struct V variable2 = {
    { 1, 0 },
    { 3, 'A', 'B', 'C'  },
    PASCAL_STRING(.pstringb, "XYZ")
};
```

[Caveat emptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caveat_emptor).
I get *warning: initialized field overwritten [-Woverride-init]*

Comment: Unfortunately this is not accepted by the compiler. No `.member` is allowed. Even the comma in `, [0} = ...` is treated as error.  I fear I need a way to build a string similar to the pstringb (with "\3", 3 is placeholder for the actual length)

Comment: @harper The reason for the still unanswered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76618119/initialize-char-array-with-a-pascal-string/76618679?noredirect=1#comment135086125_76618119) is to deal with things like  [not accepted by the compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76618119/initialize-char-array-with-a-pascal-string/76618679?noredirect=1#comment135090780_76618679).  Its OK to not address these comments, yet it makes progress slower.

Comment: @Reinstate Monica, you are right. That statement was very unspecific. To be more precise, the CodeVisionAVR compiler for AVR microcontroller doesn't support member initializers. With this background I fear that there is no way to implement the desired PASCAL_STRING macro. I will have to stick with counting each string's count if characters r use a kind of script that creates appropriate include files.